# Creating TypeScript React component dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I create component dynamically using React with TypeScript?
Assuming that I have some `RandomComponent` and I pass it as props to `renderInput`, how could I return `<RandomComponent>` from it?
TypeScript does not seem to understand something like this:

```
export const renderInput = (props) => {
  const Field: JSX.Element = props.component;
  return (
    <Field {...props} />
  )
}
```

Edit:
Made it work, but am wondering what if I wanted to add this `ComponentType` type. It works without it, but when I add it and the code looks like this:

```
  const Field: ComponentType = component;

  return (
    <Field name={name} label={label} value={value} onChange={onChange} {...props} />
  );
};
```

I get:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: any; label: any; value: any; onChange: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TS2749: 'Field' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Field'

Comment: the type for components is `ComponentType`, not `JSX.Element`

Comment: Is props.component a react element or a component?

Comment: it is a component, the problem was that my file was `.ts`, not `.tsx` and now the problem I get is:
```React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in```

Comment: In that case you should change the type as @thedude recommends

Comment: Everything works, thanks guys, the problem was that I commented out the `props.component` where I was passing it from :)

Comment: If I can ask, when I add `: ComponentType` I get an error that `... is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.` Of course I can live without `ComponentType`, but wanted to know what if I wanted to proceed with that type

Comment: I edited my post, to show you what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic type

```
export const renderInput = <T,>(props:T & {component: React.reactNode }) => {
  const Field = props.component;

  return (
    <Field {...props}/>
  )
}
```

Alternatively if only need to send a component you can send it as children

```
export const renderInput = (props: { children: React.reactNode }) => {
  const { children } = props;
  return children;
};
```

Comment: this is incorrect, the type for components is `ComponentType` not `ReactNode`